# jQuery: override a value of a property previously initialized

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object initialized in this way:

```
 $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#smoothed').signaturePad({
            drawOnly:true,  
            drawBezierCurves:true, 
            errorMessageDraw: 'Please sign',
            lineTop:200,
            validateFields: true
        });
    });
```

When i click a button, i want to override the value of "validateFields".
I tried this:

```
 <input type="button" value="back" onclick="myFunction();" />    
    <script>
       function myFunction()
       {
         $('#smoothed').prop('validateFields', 'false');    
         //second try
         $('#smoothed').attr('validateFields', 'false');
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: `prop()` and `attr()` are not the right tools here. You should instead check if your plugin supports modifying options on the fly (not all of them do).

Comment: +1 Frederic, you're passing an object to the plugin function, those are usually discarded after init and the plugin stores the settings in some other way.

Comment: Setting attribute will not change the value because `validateFields` is option for function `signaturePad`. You need to find it in jquery plugin you are using to override the options. See API doc for it.

Comment: That'll only work if the `signaturePad` saves its settings in the DOM. Check the `signaturePad` documentation for how to change settings. If all else fails, remove the element, re-add it and reinitialize the `signaturePad`.

Answer (score 0):

The default options can be changed globally for all instances of Signature Pad on the page using the jQuery plugin construct. So you can do this with following:

```
$.fn.signaturePad.validateFields = false;
```

**[More details:Changing Default Options](http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/)**

### Update

But you don't want to change it for all signature pad so you can do this:

```
var sig = $('#smoothed').signaturePad({
            drawOnly:true,  
            drawBezierCurves:true, 
            errorMessageDraw: 'Please sign',
            lineTop:200,
            validateFields: true
        });    
var api = $('#smoothed').signaturePad({validateFields:false});
api.regenerate(sig);
```

Answer (score 0):

The plugin function returns an `api` object. The object has a function `updateOptions` that you can call to update the plugin's setting for that instance.

```
var sig = $('#smoothed').signaturePad({
...

// Later
sig.updateOptions({ validateFields: false });
```